# Printing a Python dictionary in two rows with aligned columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to print a Python dictionary with keys in one row and values in another row.

Example:

```
d = {'a':'long val', 'b':None, 'long key':3, 'd':4}
```

I want to print it as

```
    a    | b | long key | d
long val |   |    3     | 4
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use str.center(int) for this purpose. Use it to get the characters centered easily and after that you just have to print | to separate the column.

Comment: there are many packages on pypi that will do this pretty well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that either you iterate twice or you build the two output lines first and then display them:

```
d = {'a': 'long val', 'b': None, 'long key': 3, 'd': 4}
headers = ""
row = ""
for k, v in d.items():
    if row != "":
        row += " | "
        headers += " | "
    max_len = max(len(str(k)), len(str(v)) if v else 1)
    headers += str(k).center(max_len)
    row += str(v).center(max_len) if v else " "
print(headers)
print(row)
```

But it looks like a lot of hassle to avoid a double iteration over a simple dict.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, here is the updated version, which is scalable

```
print(*["{!s:^16}|".format(item)  for item in d.keys()] )
print(*["{!s:^16}|".format(item)  for item in d.values()])
```

output:

```
       a        |       b        |    long key    |       d        
    long val    |      None      |       3        |       4
```

Comment: The question is how to avoid iterating twice to compute the optimal sizes for the header or value size. You are using .keys() and .values(), it's not scalable to any dict size and uses fixed 16 bytes for values.
I do like the oneliner though

Comment: @EricDarchis Yes, you are right, my old answer is not scalable, but it can adapted with list compression to achieve scalability.

Comment: It's scalable... until one of the keys or values is longer than 16 characters.